# double clicking a jqgrid row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

i need to execute some serverside code on a double click on a jqgrid row....
i tried doing this on the client side code and it seems the double click event is not firing....

.....

```
      $('#grdSearchResults').jqGrid({
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid,iRow,iCol,e) {
                var data = $('#grdSearchResults').getRowData(rowid);

                DoubleClickRow(data);
            }
        });
```

....

DoubleClickRow needs to set a few hidden fields with the data extracted from that row and then needs to click a button on the same page which initiates a serverside event...

i am using the latest jqgrid and jqjuery versions...

does anyone know how to do this....btw it needs to work  both on ie and firefox...
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so....i tried something different....i was able to solve this...

```
 function DoubleClickRow(rowid,iRow,iCol,e) {
        var txtLastResearchedDate = $('#txtLastResearchedDate');
        txtLastResearchedDate.value = jQuery('#<%=grdSearchResults.ClientID %>').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 6);

        var txtHiddenID = $('#txtHiddenID');

        txtHiddenID.value = jQuery('#<%=grdSearchResults.ClientID %>').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 5);
        var txtHiddenCaseName = $('#txtHiddenCaseName');
        txtHiddenCaseName.value = rowid;

        var txtHiddenCaseNumber = $('#txtHiddenCaseNumber');
        txtHiddenCaseNumber.value = jQuery('#<%=grdSearchResults.ClientID %>').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 2);

        var txtHiddenCaseFiledDate = $('#txtHiddenCaseFiledDate');
        txtHiddenCaseFiledDate.value = jQuery('#<%=grdSearchResults.ClientID %>').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 3);

        var txtHiddenCourtName = $('#txtHiddenCourtName');
        txtHiddenCourtName.value = jQuery('#<%=grdSearchResults.ClientID %>').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 1);

        //alert(txtHiddenCaseFiledDate.value + ' \n ' + txtHiddenCaseName.value + ' \n ' + txtHiddenCaseNumber.value + ' \n ' + txtHiddenCourtName.value + ' \n ' + txtLastResearchedDate.value + ' n\ ' + txtHiddenID.value);

        $('#<%=btnSelect.ClientID %>').click();


    }
```

so i hooked this up with the clientside events in the codebehind itself...for some reason...using the html attribute to assign the function to the event gave me runtime javascript errors...

anyway problem solved....
@ctrldot thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

I think to access the jquery grid via the new API you have to do something like,

```
jQuery('#grdSearchResults').jqGrid("getRowData",rowid)
```

You might want to toss in some alerts first to make sure it is firing, but see if you are getting js errors in firebug.

I'm assuming DoubleClickRow will make an ajax call of some sort...

Comment: i tried the above....and also tried putting alerts...i think the event is not firing...maybe i need to find each selected row and bind the dblclick to it....dont know if i can do that with this control

Comment: Maybe post your code to jqGrid help or mailing list.  We are using ondblClickRow and it works fine.....  I can't see an error in your code